# Update of Contact Owner doesn't work with Data Loader or Data Import Wizard

Tags: process-builder, data-loader

we would really appreciate someone can help me with my problem. There were experienced people in the Salesforce Community, who used to answer my questions, this has changed unfortunately with the time, so please Salesforce Community, help us to solve this issue :(.

We are facing the following issue:

We would like to update the Owner of all Contacts of an Account with the Account Owner ID value automatically with a process, so when we also use the Data Loader or Data Import Wizard we then can also do the upadate through those tools.

We build a process with the Process Builder, which looks like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

When we try to update Account per Data Import Wizard or Data Loader, the Account Owner is updated correctly, but not the Contact Owner on the children, the contacts. When we do it manually, it works.

Why? what are we doing wrong? is this an issue in Salesforce?
Please Salesforce experts, help us to know and learn here in the Community. We all need more collaboration from you :(.

Comment: If you execute the same flow by manually updated the owner form UI then is it working??

Comment: Reset the size of dataloader batch size. By defaults its 200 try to minimize it and try again.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, thanks for answering. Unfortunately answers come late here :(. I had changed the batch size to 1 but a change on accounts and their contacts didn't work with the Data Loader. So I had to write a trigger.